# Problems Installing Python igraph on Mountain Lion OS X

Tags: python, installation, python-2.7, igraph

I've installed the igraph C library using Brew,

```
sudo brew install igraph
```

I have then installed the igraph python library using pip

```
sudo pip install python-igraph
```

I go on the Python console/terminal and import the module

```
>>> import igraph
```

No problem. Then I test to see the version number

```
>>> print igraph.__version__
0.6
```

No problem there either. But when I try to create a graph.

```
>>> g = Graph(1)
```

All i get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Graph' is not defined
```

I've tried to re install everything, and it just keeps doing the same thing. Ran out of ideas now.

I don't think I'm doing anything funny, just following the instructions from [Python tutorial page](http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: When I try `brew install igraph` it returns `No available formula for igraph`. Have you added any repository to make it working?

Comment: @Hamal000, make sure you install the C igraph library. Also, brew is okay, but I prefer macport. You could also try pip-install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is written on the [tutorial page](http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html) right before the "Creating a graph from scratch" section:

> From now on, every example in the documentation will assume that igraph‘s objects and methods are imported into the main namespace (i.e., we used `from igraph import *` instead of `import igraph`). If you let igraph take its own namespace, please adjust all the examples accordingly.

So the bottom line is:

1. If you used `import igraph`, use `igraph.Graph(1)` because the `Graph` constructor then resides in the `igraph` namespace.
2. If you used `from igraph import *`, use `Graph(1)` because everything in the `igraph` module was imported into the main namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
 from igraph import *
```

and that seemed to work.

Also, starting igraph through the terminal directly with

```
$ igraph
```